# PHP XML Soap request

Tags: php, xml, soap

How I can do below soap request in php,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v="http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ditws/TaxCredMismatch/v_1_0">
    <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
        <v:getTaxCredMismatchRequest>
        <LoginInfo>
            <userName>XXXXXXXXXX</userName>
            <password>XXXXXXXXXX</password>
        </LoginInfo>
        <UserInput>
            <panNo>XXXXXXXXXX</panNo>
            <asseessmentyear>XXXX-XX</asseessmentyear>
        </UserInput>
    </v:getTaxCredMismatchRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried below code,

```
<?php
    $url = "https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingWS/ditws/getTaxCredMismatchRequest.wsdl";
    try {        
        $options = array( 
                'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 
                'exceptions'=>true, 
                'trace'=>1, 
                'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE 
            );         
        $client = new SoapClient($url,$options);
        $requestParams = array(
            'userName' => 'AJAPA5855E',
            'password' => 'pass123',
            'panNo' =>  'AJAPA5855E',
            'asseessmentyear' => '2014-15'
        );        
        $response = $client->__soapCall("getTaxCredMisMatch", array($requestParams));
        var_dump($response);
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
?>
```

but getting the response as

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'LoginInfo' property
```

I know, I'm sending the parameter in correct way, may I know how to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used that soap client, but I would expect this:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingWS/ditws/getTaxCredMismatchRequest.wsdl";
    try {        
        $options = array( 
                'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 
                'exceptions'=>true, 
                'trace'=>1, 
                'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE 
            );         
        $client = new SoapClient($url,$options);
        $requestParams = array(
            'LoginInfo' => array (
                'userName' => 'AJAPA5855E',
                'password' => 'pass123',
            ),
            'UserInput' => array (
                'panNo' =>  'AJAPA5855E',
                'asseessmentyear' => '2014-15'
            )
        );        
        $response = $client->__soapCall("getTaxCredMisMatch", array($requestParams));
        var_dump($response);
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
?>
```

However as said above, this is just a wild guess. It certainly would make sense to take a look at the documentation of that extension: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php. Such things should be explained in there...

Answer (score 0):

Using the WSDL from https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingWS/ditws/getTaxCredMismatchRequest.wsdl, you could generate the corresponding package from [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com) in order to be sure on how to structure your request in PHP as every element will be a PHP object with setters/getters. It uses the native PHP SoapClient class so you'll understand easily and quickly who to send these requests if you're familiar with PHP